# How to track virus on WordPress site

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, cpanel, whm

I run a dedicated server with WHM/cPanel CentOS Apache.

One of my accounts on cPanel have a WordPress site that some how got a virus. 
They use it to send mails / inject affiliate links etc.

I have ran AV scanners and also manually cleaned everything i can find, but the virus keep coming back. Is there any way i can log when someone uploads a file via PHP or even create or modify a file?

I have been going trough log files but i keep always seems to miss something so i want to try back-trace it and find the file they use to upload the PHP files with.

Comment: Use "find" to find files newer than a certain reference file. Upgrade the wordpress installation.

Comment: Issue is that the hacker or what to call him/her is modifying the dates on the files they upload so they are same as all the other files.

Comment: Are the users or admins upload files?

Comment: @A.Blub they are in a cpanel account so they are isolated to that user only. Issue is i have a hard time cleaning this site and back when the virus hit for the first time i did not have a backup. So now i spend few hours a month cleaning it, but it keeps coming back. So i need to find the source from where they mange to upload the files from which PHP file it is.

Comment: If you want to know where the source is, then check your access log for POST Requests. Check the IP too. Maybe you are lucky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use wordfence security plugin that will scan your whole wordpress site and also stop any type of injection. You will not face any trouble after this.

Comment: Issue is its spread outside of wordpress so its standalone PHP files.